# Cronómetro DownTimer Android que no se detenga en cero

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

La cuestión (en apariencia) es simple. Un countDownTimer o Chronometer que cuando llegue a cero siga descontando en números negativos, que no se detenga.
Eventualmente lo detendré al pulsar un botón, pero hasta que no pulse el botón el cronómetro deberá seguir descontando, aún luego de haber llegado a cero.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Has intentado algo? Muestra lo que has hecho para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DownUpTimer(int countDownTimeSeconds) {
    this.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countDownTimeSeconds * 1000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millis) {
            parseMillisToHourMinutsSeconds(millis / 1000);
            if (onTickListener != null) {
                onTickListener.onTick(horas,minutos,segundos,cronoPositivo);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            cronoPositivo = false;
            countUpTimer = new Timer("upTimer");
            countUpTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    parseMillisToHourMinutsSeconds((long) counter);
                    counter++;
                    if (onTickListener != null) {
                        onTickListener.onTick(horas,minutos,segundos,cronoPositivo);
                    }
                }
            },0,1000);
        }
    };
}

public void start() {
    countDownTimer.start();
}

public void stop () {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    if (countUpTimer != null) countUpTimer.cancel();
}

private void parseMillisToHourMinutsSeconds (Long segundos) {
    Float seg = segundos.floatValue();
    Float calculodehoras = seg / 3600;
    Integer cantidaddehoras = calculodehoras.intValue();
    Float calculodeminutos = seg / 60;
    Integer cantidaddeminutos = calculodeminutos.intValue();
    Float calculodesegundos = seg - (cantidaddehoras * 3600) - (cantidaddeminutos * 60);
    Integer cantidaddesegundos = calculodesegundos.intValue();
    this.horas = cantidaddehoras.longValue();
    this.minutos = cantidaddeminutos.longValue();
    this.segundos = cantidaddesegundos.longValue();
}

public void setOnTickListener(OnTickListener onTickListener) {
    this.onTickListener = onTickListener;
}

public interface OnTickListener {
    void onTick(Long horas, Long minutos, Long segundos, Boolean cronoPositivo);
}
```

Comment: Esa es una clase que administra dos contadores; uno descendente y luego, sobre el onFinish se crea un nuevo timer ascendente (para comenzar a contar los números negativos). El problema es que cuando el countDownTimer llega a cero, hace una pausa (exactamente de 1 seg.) y luego comienza el nuevo timer a contar ascendentemente. No puedo eliminar esa "pausa" de 1 segundo.

Comment: @Einer A partir de esa clase, se actualiza un textView con los números.